# Kernel Mode Driver Support in Visual Studio

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, kernel, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to write a Windows Kernel mode driver in VS Community 2019, following [the official documentation here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/gettingstarted/writing-a-very-small-kmdf--driver). As prerequisites, the Windows SDK as well as the Windows Driver kit are required. I installed both of them. Unfortunately, VS19 has an updated menu for creating a new project that differs from the one in the documentation. I fail to find the entry for a kernel mode driver, even after confirming all dependencies in the VS installer, double checking version numbers (the SDK and WDK are indeed for VS19) and restarting Windows.
[Restarting the installer of the WDK confirms that the kit is installed, but VS still does not show an entry.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tng7x.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The article
[What's new in driver development for Windows 10](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/what-s-new-in-driver-development#wdk-supports-visual-studio-2019)
may be useful:

> In Visual Studio 2019 the WDK Driver menu has been moved to live under the Extension menu as seen below.
>
> [image]
>
> **Driver Templates discoverability**
>
> In Visual Studio 2019 the WDK Driver templates will be discoverable
>   under Project Type, Drivers. The Driver Project Type will appear in
>   the first official update release of Visual Studio 2019. Until then
>   the Driver templates can be discovered by searching for them in the
>   search menu.
>
> [image]

Comment: I'm afraid my installation is faultier than I thought. I neither see the entry for a kernel mode driver nor the Driver entry under extensions. As you can see in my screenshot above, the WDK states that it is installed and up to date. It created a file Windows Kits under Program Files (x86) as well as in the Community folder of the VS install. Is there any special plugin I need to install in addition to [the WDK](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/download-the-wdk) or is my install location wrong?

Comment: It probably only means that when moving in Visual Studio 2019 the WDK Driver menu, Microsoft forgot to port this to the Community version, or maybe has not yet done so, or maybe even will never do so in order to force you to get the paid version. I suggest, until this problem clarifies itself, to keep your old environment around for the purpose of creating the projects via the UI. This is hoping that everything else beside creating projects does still work.